# Get SQL distinct data Bookshelf Model

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I am trying to get distinct data from MySQL database by the bookshelf model.

Department Controller:

```
Department.distinct('departmentName').fetchAll().then((result) => {
            return res.send({
                status: '204',
                message: 'Data is Fetched',
                error: false,
                data: result
            })
        }
```

Department Model:

```
Bookshelf.model('Department' , {
    tableName:'departments',
    hasSecurePassword: true,
    hasTimestamps : ['created_at' , 'updated_at'],
    softDelete: true,
    hidden: ['deleted_at'],

    parse: function(response){
        if(response.allowUseOfMyContactInformation != null)
        response.allowUseOfMyContactInformation = !!+response.allowUseOfMyContactInformation;
        return response;
    }
})
```

Someone please help I am getting error "Department.distinct is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long google. I found that query groupBy save my life:

```
dashboard_department = (req, res) => {
    try {
        Department.query({
            groupBy: 'departmentName'
        }).fetchAll().then((result) => {
            return res.send({
                status: '204',
                message: 'Data is Fetched',
                error: false,
                data: result
            })
        }).catch((error) => {
            return res.send({
                status: '404',
                message: 'Data is not fetched',
                error: true,
                data: {}
            })
        })

    } catch (e) {
        return res.send({
            status: '404',
            message: 'Internal Server Error',
            error: true,
            data: {}
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to do a query on the model instead of object of the Department model.

Make changes into your department controller

First, you need to import your Department model in your Department controller

```
       const Department = require('your Department model path');
       const department = new Department();
       department.distinct('departmentName').fetchAll().then((result) => {
        return res.send({
            status: '204',
            message: 'Data is Fetched',
            error: false,
            data: result
        })
```

I hope this will help you. If you have any problem though let me know.

Comment: No, That does not work. I exported this model. So, It work like a object. I am doing more stuff with that Department but there is problem only with distinct.

Comment: const Bookshelf = require('../bookshelf')

module.exports = Bookshelf.model('Department', {
    tableName: 'departments',
    hasSecurePassword: true,
    hasTimestamps: ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
    softDelete: true,
    hidden: ['deleted_at'],

    parse: function (response) {
        if (response.allowUseOfMyContactInformation != null)
            response.allowUseOfMyContactInformation = !!+response.allowUseOfMyContactInformation;
        return response;
    }
})